# Search for a specific word stored in one column which has so much data

Tags: excel-formula

I have a free text column full of contact details. I want to extract realtion ship out of the contact details. I tried different formulas, but didnt work. Even I have added a column with relationship status and tried

```
=INDEX(D$2:D$5,MATCH(1,IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(D$2:D$5,A2)),0,1),0),1)
```

but it didnt work.

For ex:

```
Contact Details Column:
Matthew Brown: Wife: 937268475663 (home) or 939848399384 (mobile)
Bill Benoit: Father: 7494785736784
Spouse - Matha Nocon - 948479 289374
Mrs Elaine Batty: Wife: 29474567334
Iain Beveridge020 8877 3537
Janice Waddy01482 581000 Work 07986501322 Mobile
Tony Salter (Father)Tel: 0207 583 5000
Mrs Amanda Bluff - 01507 466198
Paula Washburn[Sister] - 87362 741895 [Home]
Cliff Potter (Husband) - 0263 88472363(Work)
```

I want an excle formula that searches relationship from ralationship status column inside the contact details column and extract relationship (wife, husband, etc.).

Comment: The problem I am having is with your data layout.  There is no clear way of identifying where  the relationship occurs.  The only way I could envision doing this is through VBA and having a preset list of relationship terms.  Check each relationship term to see if it exist in the string and if so display that term.  The problem with that is it a person's name contains or is the same as one of the relationship terms.  Ie First name John, Last name Brother.

Answer (score 0):

Hi Kaliakanhu Panigrahi,

You use array in your formula and you forgot put it on {}.

You can do it by pressing Ctrl + Shift + Enter when you are in the formula cell.

When I did this it works fine for me.